# Invalid bind expression type error in apex soql trigger.new

Tags: apex

When executing the following code in an after insert trigger, I am getting the error

> "System.QueryException: Invalid bind expression type of
> TransactionItem__c does not match domain of foreign key Class"

```
Integer myAggregate = [SELECT Count() 
            FROM TransactionItem__c 
            WHERE Transaction__c = :Trigger.new];
System.debug(myAggregate);
```

What could be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Try `Transaction__r.Id IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet()` (_assuming the trigger is on Transaction__c object_)

Comment: Trigger is on the child object TransactionItem__c. master-detail relationship filed is Transaction on the child object. The fix ran without errors but debug only printed count 0, it should be 3 actually as it has 3 related child records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Trigger.new domain is TransactionItem__c, you would also need to bind to an Id field of the same domain. In this case, what you need to do is to pull the Transaction__c Id values out of the records, and then filter on that.

```
Set<Id> transactionIds = new Set<Id>();
for(TransactionItem__c record:Trigger.new) {
  transactionIds.add(record.Transaction__c);
}
Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
  select count(id) itemCount, Transaction__c Id
  from TransactionItem__c
  where Transaction__c = :transactionIds
  group by Transaction__c
]);
```

Note that there may be more than one record in Trigger.new, so we use a map to keep track of how many TransactionItem__c records are per Transaction__c.